# Swift string from web request JSON has line breaks - how to remove line breaks?

Tags: ios, json, swift, string, swift3

I have a String I am displaying in a UILabel and it has what seems to be several line breaks.

Here is the link to the raw JSON data (text is in key "`flavor_text`"): http://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon-species/1/

Here is what the string looks like:

```
{
   "flavor_text":"Bulbasaur can be seen napping in bright sunlight.\nThere is a seed on its back. By soaking up the sun\u2019s rays,\nthe seed grows progressively larger."
}
```

I have tried using the following trimming code:

```
myUILabel.text = flavorText.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
```

but the line breaks persist. Any suggestions?

Comment: btw..trimmingCharacters doesn't work here because it only trims the specified characters that are in at the beginning or end of a string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you try with `replacingOccurrences`.

```
myUILabel.text = flavorText.replacingOccurrences(of target: "\n", with replacement: "")
```